# Is this an AI bot? Can't tell if answer is from a real person

Tags: discussion

This question of Baez is getting a string of strange answers.  I can't tell if the author is a mathematician, but their answers don't make much sense to me.

[Which finite abelian groups aren't homotopy groups of spheres?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377545/which-finite-abelian-groups-arent-homotopy-groups-of-spheres)

Comment: Definitely a person using an AI bot, and they seem to have been taken care of now.